# java.io.IOException: Unable to negotiate SSL transaction, no keystore? in JMeter 5.0

Tags: java, jmeter

Trying to record my mobile application calls using JMeter and facing issues. I have installed `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` from laptop to mobile phone. Added the laptop IP address to `remote_hosts` in `jmeter.properties`. Still I'm getting below error:

```
1,036 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [47086]  Exception when processing sample
java.io.IOException: Unable to negotiate SSL transaction, no keystore?
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.startSSL(Proxy.java:448) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:194) [ApacheJMeter
```

Getting above during login itself in mobile application and login is not working.
I'm also getting below error in logs:

```
2018-12-12 12:42:30,321 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [46349] ...
2018-12-12 12:42:30,321 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [46349]  Problem with keystore
java.io.IOException:   >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must begin with a letter <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias 4o8rhl3t1a.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com -dname "cn=4o8rhl3t1a.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com, o=JMeter Proxy (TEMPORARY TRUST ONLY)" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext san=dns:4o8rhl3t1a.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:172) ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateSignedCert(KeyToolUtils.java:286) ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateHostCert(KeyToolUtils.java:277) ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.updateKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1606) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.getSSLSocketFactory(Proxy.java:326) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.startSSL(Proxy.java:431) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:194) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC-1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) domain name must begin with the letter so the options are in:

1. Leave `HTTPS Domains` field of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) blank

   [image]
2. Consider alternative recording option, i.e. there is [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) which doesn't require setting up proxy settings and importing SSL certificates.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, please find below:
> HTTPS Domain was always blank for all alternatives i tried.
> Let me try with JMeter Chrome Extension and come back.

But I'm still curious to understand the issue why it is not working with the setup with JMeter.